# Counting set accumulations of elapsed time with lubridate

Tags: r, time, lubridate

I have a dataset that contains a dateTime column.  I need to count the distinct number of 4 hour stretches for each unique ID.  Here's what I have so far...

```
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)

# Fake data
myID <- c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2)
timeStamp1 <- c("2017-08-01 00:01:00", "2017-08-01 00:02:00", "2017-08-01 00:03:00", "2017-08-01 00:04:00", 
                "2017-08-01 03:00:00", "2017-08-01 05:00:00", "2017-08-01 05:01:00", "2017-08-01 05:02:00",
               "2017-08-01 01:00:00", "2017-08-01 04:00:00", "2017-08-01 04:59:00", "2017-08-01 05:00:01", 
               "2017-08-01 08:00:00", "2017-08-01 09:01:00", "2017-08-01 13:01:00", "2017-08-01 13:02:00")
df1 <- data.frame(myID, timeStamp1)
dt1 <- setDT(df1)

# Convert to date type
dt1 <- dt1[, BTS := ymd_hms(timeStamp1)]

# Order by MMSI and then TimeStamp
dt1 <- dt1[order(myID, BTS)]

# Create lagged time
dt1 <- dt1[, l_BTS := shift(BTS), by = myID]

# Create span variable
dt1 <- dt1[, spans1 := abs(l_BTS - BTS)]
```

I think this involves some combination of `difftime()` and/or `as.duration()` and/or `cumsum()` but I keep digging myself deeper holes. Desired output looks like this:

[image]

I thought this would produce my desired results but I'm definitely doing something wrong here:

```
# Count distinct transits by 4 hour blocks
dt1 <- dt1[, tFlag := c(FALSE, diff(as.Date(BTS))) > .1666667, by = myID]
dt1 <- dt1[, t_Count := cumsum(tFlag), by = myID]
```

Comment: I did not understand what you mean by "... the distinct number of 4 hour stretches for each unique ID." Are you referring to the number of 4-hour blocks between the minimum and the maximum timestamps within each myID?

Comment: Yes, to clarify these are shipping vessel data.  I need to count how many 4-hour blocks each ship (unique ID) is out... so if one unique ID had data for one complete 24-hour day, I need to count this as 6 "transits" (24 hours/4 hours).

Comment: So, how do we handle fractions? Ie. if a ship is at sea by 4 hours and 10 minutes, do you want the result counted as "1 transit" or as "2 transits"?

Comment: I think rounding down would be the correct way to handle this... so 4 hours 10 minutes = 1 transit.

Comment: I updated the answer with the floor() function to obtain the number of transits per myID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if I understood you well, but if you need the difference between the earliest and the latest timestamps within each group of myIDs, you can do this:

```
library(tidyverse)

dt1 %>% group_by(myID) %>% 
        summarise(min = min(BTS), 
                  max = max(BTS)) %>% 
        mutate(delta = difftime(max, min, units = "hours")/4,
               transits = as.numeric(floor(difftime(max, min, units = "hours")/4)))

# A tibble: 2 x 5
  myID  min                  max                  delta            transits
 <dbl>  <dttm>               <dttm>               <time>           <dbl>              
     1  2017-08-01 00:01:00  2017-08-01 05:02:00  1.25416666666667 1                   
     2  2017-08-01 01:00:00  2017-08-01 13:02:00  3.00833333333333 3
```

Comment: This does it!  I decided to remove the floor() and keep the decimals for precision.